# Difference between "this" and without "this" in java

Tags: java, constructor

I am really confused about the keyword "this" and without "this" on classes, because i think it is the same :

```
public class thisthing {
    public int a;
    public arrays(){
        a=1;

    }
    public void A(){
        this.a=10;
    }
    public void printa(){
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(this.a);
    }
}
```

if I call `printa` without calling `A()` I get this results :

```
1
1
```

but if i do the same with calling `A()` :

```
10
10
```

What is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 4):

Here there is no difference. For a difference, you would need a ***local*** variable with that name. For example,

```
public void printa(int a){
    System.out.println(a); // the argument a
    System.out.println(this.a); // the field a
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> What is the difference between these two?

If an identifier unambiguously refers to an instance variable in the class, there is no difference between using `this` and not. However, if the instance variable is shadowed by a local variable or a function argument, using `this` forces the compiler to use the instance variable instead. For example

```
public class Main 
{
    int a = 1;

    void bar(int a)
    {
        System.out.println("local " + a);
        System.out.println("instance " + this.a);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Main().bar(2);
    }
}
```

Prints

```
local 2
instance 1
```

I find this is most useful when assigning values in a constructor. You don't have to think of new variable names for the constructor arguments.

```
public class Main {

    int a;

    Main(int a)
    {
        this.a = a; // Assigns the instance variable from the argument
    }

    void bar(int a)
    {
        System.out.println("local " + a);
        System.out.println("instance " + this.a);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Main(3).bar(2);
    }
}
```

Prints

```
local 2
instance 3
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to the current object - the instance of the class in whose method is the scope.

In the scope of the method you could see local variables, member variables and static variables. If you have a name collision between a local variable and member variable you could use `this` to differentiate between the two - you explicitly state that you work with the member variable.

In case you don't have a local variable with matching name you could not use the `this` reference - the member variable would be recognised easily.

Example:

```
new MyClass().printAVar(1);

class MyClass {
    private int x = 2;

    public void printAVar(int x) {
        // this.x == 2;
        // x == 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"this" is a keyword.
"this" is a reference variable that refers to the current object.

without "this"

```
class Student{
String name;  
void data(String name){  
name=name; 
} 
void disp(){   
System.out.println("Name:"+name); 
} 
public static void main(String args[]){  
Student s1=new Student();
s1.data("A");
s1.disp();  
}}
```

Output

```
Output:- Name:null
```

Now using "this" keyword

```
class Student {
String name;  
void data(String name){  
this.name=name; 
} 
void disp(){   
System.out.println("Name:"+name); 
} 
public static void main(String args[]){  
Student s1=new Student();
s1.data("A");
s1.disp();  
}}
```

Now Output will be

```
Output:- Name:A
```

Answer (score 0):

this is used to say you want the "a" from the class, not the parameter

```
 public void printa(int a){
        System.out.println(a); //print the parameter of function
        System.out.println(this.a); //print the attribute of the class
    }
```

for example, if you call `printa(2)` :

```
2
1
```

Comment: Your method is broke.